# Google drive folder access from website registered members

Tags: google-drive-api

I have to develop a web site where only registered and accepted members will have access to my GDrive space in  specific personal folders I created, one folder for each member. I want all members to access their Gdrive folder from a login page in the web site.

I have a database where I store Username and Password from the registration process, and want to give permission to the folder associated to every members based on that username and password. The Gdrive Share process, as it is, is not working for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/).